# Display aggregate value next to label in frame in treemap

Tags: plotly-python, plotly-express

Following my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331001/how-to-show-values-used-for-color-in-texttemplate-in-px-treemap), I am now building nice treemaps.

I would like to show the aggregate value of the branch next to its label (Equities and ETFs). I have looked at `px.treemap` and `fig.update_layout` parameters but I can't find what I am looking for. Is it possible ?

```
fig = px.treemap(shares_data,
                 title=tit,
                 path=['Type', 'Stock'],
                 values='Holding',
                 color='Growth',
                 color_continuous_scale=[(0, "red"), (scale_mid, "yellow"), (1, "green")],
                  )

fig.update_layout(width=1600, height=950,
                  paper_bgcolor='black',
                  plot_bgcolor='black'
                  )

fig.update_traces(root_color="black")

fig.update_layout(title_font_color="white")

fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=dict(tickfont={"color":'white'},titlefont={"color":'white'}),)

fig.data[0].customdata = fig.data[0].marker.colors

fig.data[0].texttemplate = "<b>%{label}</b><br>Holding: R%{value:.2f}<br>Growth: <b>%{customdata:.1f}</b>%<br>"
```

[image: treemap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Brendan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6814713/brendan)'s comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60637203/3355860) answer, I was able to pre-calculate the proportional values i.e. `holding * growth` for each holding, and then get the average for each section.

The part of writing to the csv changed to:

```
etfavg = etftot/etfcount
equitiesavg = equitiestot/equitiescount
etfval = '<b>ETFs: ' + str(round(etftot, 1)) + '%</b>'
equitiesval = '<b>Equities: ' + str(round(equitiestot, 1)) + '%</b>'

# write data to csv
for i in fullset:
    if i in etfs:
        line = [etfval, i, fullset[i][0], fullset[i][1]]
    else:
        line = [equitiesval, i, fullset[i][0], fullset[i][1]]
    writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Funny, the values are in the hover data, but there doesn't seem to be a property to display it :-/